# Ninject with WCF Application Error

Tags: wcf, ninject

In Visual Studio 2013, I've set up a WCF Application.  My setup is exactly like the example posted at https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Wcf/tree/master/src/Examples.  When I try to import my service reference from another project, I get the error below.  I have have added Ninject.Extensions.Factory to the WCF project (and the referencing project) using Nuget, and still get the same error.

```
Warning 1   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Ninject.Extensions.Factory, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IEnrollmentService'] C:\...\Reference.svcmap 1   1
```

Comment: which version of ninject.extensions.factory have you added to the project? Maybe an [assembly redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would help/ Is the assembly being copied to the right location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing the Service Reference, click the Advanced button, then uncheck "reuse types in referenced assemblies".